# Run Web app with Bokeh plots in an offline mode? Where to dl Required Bokeh files

Tags: javascript, python, css, bokeh

I have a web application with python controllers, where output plots are plotted by Bokeh.  In my master template.html file I load bokeh-0.9.2.min.css and bokeh-0.9.2.min.js as shown below.

My question is "If I run my web app as a browser app in offline mode, Is it possible to download these two files into my static/jss folder and run it offline?"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.2.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question, there is now a convenient way to load the Bokeh JS and CSS files inline instead of via CDN. This can be done by setting the **mode** argument to **inline** in the [io.output_file](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html#bokeh.io.output_file) function:

```
output_file('plot.html', title='Bokeh Plot', autosave=False, mode='inline', root_dir=None)
```

Comment: Great answer, solved my issue! But it looks like the autosave parameter was removed from output_file function

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you should be able to download the js and css files from the cdn (using wget or similar) into static/js and static/css files. Then you just have to change the href/src paths to your local directories to load the statics.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about CDN (using wget or similar)?

Comment: This can now be done by setting the 'mode' argument to 'inline' in the io.output_file function.

Answer (score 2):

I examined the head on an html file produced by a bokeh python script `bokeh.plotting.output_file` and noticed a reference to **lib/site-packages/bokeh/server/static/js/bokeh.min.js**