# Saving html file with images in bokeh

Tags: python, image, plot, bokeh

I'm creating a bokeh plot containing several images. 
I create and show my file like this:

```
output_file(my_dir + "Graphs\\graph")
show(bar)
```

It then shows me the plot and creates a graph.html file in my directory "Graphs". But when I open the html later, the plot doesn't contain the images.
How can I save the html file, so that it contains the images as well?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As the documentation mentions, you have two ways to achieve this:

- using [`save()`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html#bokeh.io.save) instead of `show()`

  ```
  from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save
  p = figure(title="Basic Title", plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
  p.circle([1, 2], [3, 4])
  output_file("test.html")
  save(p)
  ```
- using the [`file_html`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#standalone-html) function, which is low-level

  ```
  from bokeh.plotting import figure
  from bokeh.resources import CDN
  from bokeh.embed import file_html

  plot = figure()
  plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

  html = file_html(plot, CDN, "my plot")

  with open("/myPath.html") as f:
      f.write(html)
  ```

Comment: I tried both options and I still encounter the problem of the images not showing in the saved html file.

Comment: In that case, it might be a problem with the CSS/JS resources. Can you share a screenshot of the Chrome console when you open your HTML file?

Comment: It says:
[bokeh] ImageURL unable to load [mypath] image after 0 retries

But the images have the path [mypath].

Comment: The path looks like this "file:\\C:\Users\mydir\projects\image1.png"

Comment: And how did you load that image with Bokeh? Using image_url() method? I'd say that with local files, 99% of issues are caused by paths… :)

Comment: Ohh now it works, I used to open the html files out of Pycharm but opening them directly from the folder worked :)

Comment: Try to use the os library to deal with paths... it saves a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 13):

In case you are running into problems (especially working in an offline environment), you may want to consider adding the mode='inline' parameter:

```
output_file('plot.html', mode='inline')
```

This ensures that the required js/css is included in your output html. In this way, you create a standalone html.

Combining with the existing code, this results in:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save
p = figure(title="Basic Title", plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p.circle([1, 2], [3, 4])
output_file('plot.html', mode='inline')
save(p)
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421734/run-web-app-with-bokeh-plots-in-an-offline-mode-where-to-dl-required-bokeh-file) for further reference.